# Scroll to element next to current on

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, slide

When I click an arrow button, a window scrolls to the next element, but when I scroll down and click a random element, it would first go back to the element I clicked before, or, if I don't click, it goes to the first element.

I want it to scroll next to current clicked element. Everything is bubbling.

The site I working on, where the situation appears - http://dawidjarzabek.pl/test

jQuery:

```
var currentElement = $(".post");

$('.post #nav a.prev').click(function() {
    currentElement = currentElement.prev();
    $.scrollTo(currentElement, 800);
});

$('.post #nav a.next').click(function() {
    currentElement = currentElement.next();
    $.scrollTo(currentElement, 800);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="section">

    <div class="post position">
        <div id="photo"><center><img src="photos/studio/1.jpg" /></center></div>
        <div id="nav"><a class="prev"><img src="images/icon_top.png" /></a><a class="next"><img src="images/icon_bottom.png" /></a></div>
        <div id="text">
            <h1>Modelka: </h1>
            <h2></h2>
            <h1>Wizaż : </h1>
            <h2></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post position">
        <div id="photo"><center><img src="photos/studio/2.jpg" /></center></div>
        <div id="nav"><a class="prev"><img src="images/icon_top.png" /></a><a class="next"><img src="images/icon_bottom.png" /></a></div>
        <div id="text">
            <h1>Modelka: </h1>
            <h2></h2>
            <h1>Wizaż : </h1>
            <h2></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

[the rest .post and .section]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.post #nav a.prev').click(function() {
    $.scrollTo($(this).closest('.post').prev(),800);
});

$('.post #nav a.next').click(function() {
    $.scrollTo($(this).closest('.post').next(),800);
});
```

And you don't have to store variable currentElement. ;)